# Is it possible to replicate a table with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a table using flexbox but I'm a little stuck right now.

I can make the whole table align - and make the columns align, but I'm unsure how to get both columns and rows to match up.

Here's what I have so far - the example shows exactly where I'm failing:

https://jsfiddle.net/10Lfd5wp/

```
<div class="flex-table">
    <div class="item">
        <div>Name</div>
        <div>ASP.NET_SessionId</div>
        <div>visit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item flex">
        <div>Usage</div>
        <div>Identifies a session (visit), and allows user specific data to be preserved across pages and page updates.</div>

.flex-table {
  /* 2009 spec */
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* 2012 spec */
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* Standard spec */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  border: solid 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.flex-table .item > * {
  padding: 0.8rem;
}
.flex-table .item > *:first-child {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
.flex-table .item > * ~ * {
  border-top: solid 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.flex-table > .item ~ .item {
  border-left: solid 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.flex-table .item.flex {
  /* 2009 spec - limited */
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  /* 2012 onwards */
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can it...sure...but not with the same structure so I guess the answer is "NO". If you want a table...use one...this looks like a good spot for it frankly,

Comment: Point taken - was doing a little experimentation, but it is easier with a table.

Comment: No hassle...the issue is, of course, that you are are working with two wrapping flex containers and one cannot affect the children of other.

Comment: Are you still interested in building a flexbox that emulates a table? If so, please provide a few more details about how you want it to perform. Wrapping? Colspan or rowspan anywhere? Header? etc. For certain, a flexbox is not a table, but it can be structured to be similar with the benefit of flex properties..

Comment: What's the goal behind using flex for a table? If there something you are trying to do that isn't supported by `display: table`?